# How to execute Python Api project in Azure function to run as api

Tags: python, api, azure-functions

Where when the code gets executed, it takes file from a specified location to convert to json indexing and respond back to the user query, for example OpenAI embedding.

```
import os
from langchain import OpenAI
from gpt_index import SimpleDirectoryReader, GPTSimpleVectorIndex, LLMPredictor, PromptHelper
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

def env(apikey):
    os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = apikey

def construct_index(directory_path):
    max_input_size = 4096
    num_outputs = 512
    max_chunk_overlap = 20
    chunk_size_limit = 600
    prompt_helper = PromptHelper(max_input_size, num_outputs, max_chunk_overlap, chunk_size_limit=chunk_size_limit)
    llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(llm=OpenAI(temperature=0.7, model_name="text-davinci-003", max_tokens=num_outputs))
    documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(directory_path).load_data()
    index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex(documents, llm_predictor=llm_predictor, prompt_helper=prompt_helper)
    index.save_to_disk('index.json')
    return index

def chatbot(input_text):
    index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex.load_from_disk('index.json')
    response = index.query(input_text, response_mode="compact")
    return response.response

index = construct_index("docs") #location where it take the file for indexing.

@app.route('/testapi/<apikey>/<input>')
def query(apikey,input):
    akey = env(apikey)
    req = chatbot(input)
    return req

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I have tried creating the function app on azure portal but unable to use my Python code, it's failing.

Comment: Could you please help us with more insights like sample input, expected output and also the current error message.

Comment: Are you referring to these OpenApi embedding https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/tutorials/embeddings?tabs=command-line

Comment: openai embedding through langchain and gpt_index, i was trying to use, however i managed to deploy the same on azure functions but post deployment, the url i have received isnt working.

Comment: Are you following any specific documentation if yes could you please share it and also you have mentioned that "URl i have isn't working " --> does that mean the function app root url is not working or could help us what is the error message that you are seeing

Comment: Result: Failure Exception: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'index.json' Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 357, in _handle__function_load_request func = loader.load_function( File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 44, in call return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 132, @DasariKamali

Comment: it seems i have to save my index.json file temporary or what are the other way to do it  because after deployment azure function server, it failing with the above error ..please help

Comment: Is that index.json file is storing under /home path or a different path

Comment: under the same folder where my python code exist "C:\Users\sam\OneDrive\Desktop\firstproject"